# Unable to install the scrypt gem on fedora 21 machine

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, fedora

I am stuck about the issues, Which coming on my fedora 21 server. Every thing is working like successfully installed the following..

1. RVM
2. Ruby 2.1.3
3. Mysql

When I am going to run command

```
bundle install
```

In the middle of the bundle, It abort with the message like please refer the attached image for the same.

[image]

Please help me to get resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The errors accused by GCC are about the flags used, -msse and -msse2, they are for x86 architectures but your kernel is arm.

Edit:
If you're using rvm with ruby 2.1.3 the cflags for scrypt gem are set in the Rakefile:
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@yourgemset/gems/scrypt-1.2.1/ext/scrypt/Rakefile

You should remove the flags -msse and -msee2, I'm not entirely sure of the consequences. Maybe you'll need to change the -arch flag too, it probably is set to x86_64.